# Formatting Javascript datetime month year

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

I'm trying to format Javascript datetime, year and month information to something like this:

```
//"Mon, Nov 5 08:46:20 PM"
```

To do that, I am following Mozilla documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#) as shown below:

```js
var options = {
  weekday: 'short',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: "2-digit",
  minute: "2-digit",
  second: "2-digit",
  hour12: true
};
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', options));
// always returns "Mon, Nov 5, 8:44:10 PM"
```

Why is the `hour` in 1-digit format although I specified it as '2-digit'? How can I achieve the format stated in the beginning of this question? Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: Not sure it’s relevant but what environment do you use to test? (Which browser or is this NodeJs?)

Comment: @stealththeninja I'm using latest Chrome browser's console. Hope that answers your question...

Comment: @Barmar did you check the spec link included in the question? And momentjs, while being good at dates and especially time zones and locales, is a big library.

Comment: Looks like a Chrome bug to me.

Comment: If you set "hour12: false" seems to work, looks like a bug.

Comment: See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=527926 This is for `DateTimeFormat.format()` but I expect `toLocaleDateString()` uses the same code, and it's marked WONTFIX. They claim it's following the spec.

Comment: Seems like a spec issue instead so there's no other way but to create your own function to have 2-digit hour with 12-hour time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
 to fix that issue:

```js
const options = {
  weekday: 'short',
  month: 'short',
  day: 'numeric',
  hour: "2-digit",
  minute: "2-digit",
  second: "2-digit",
  hour12: true
};

// Tue, Nov 6, 04:04:55 AM: 
console.log(new Date(1541473495383).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options).replace(/, (\d):/, ', 0$1:'));

// Tue, Nov 6, 10:04:55 AM:
console.log(new Date(1541495095383).toLocaleDateString('en-US', options).replace(/, (\d):/, ', 0$1:'));

// Now:
console.log(new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-US', options).replace(/, (\d):/, ', 0$1:'));
```

What `.replace(/, (\d):/, ', 0$1:')` does is:

- Match the hour part (that comes after a comma and a space and before a colon) only when it has a single digit (`\d`); otherwise, it won't match and it won't replace anything.
- Captures that digit.
- Replace the whole match with exactly the same thing but adding an additional `0` before the hour digit, which we can access in the replacement string as `$1`.